# Reading Text File in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a big data in this format and I want to extract some information from it:

```
[**] [122:1:0] (portscan) TCP Portscan [**]
[Priority: 3] 
04/13-07:54:00.585009 192.168.2.136 -> 192.168.1.14
PROTO:255 TTL:0 TOS:0x0 ID:62399 IpLen:20 DgmLen:165 DF
```

How I should read this text file in javascript?

Comment: Server-side (Node) JS, or in the browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - read local text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file)

Comment: Are you asking how to parse this text, or how to load this text into JavaScript? If load, then are you asking how to do it in the browser, or on server-side?

Comment: It depends on (a) what tool you are using to run the JS and (b) where you want to read the file from (local file, making an http request, user posting it over http)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK This is my solution to extract the information

```js
function readTextFile(file_name)
{
    var file = new XMLHttpRequest();
    file.open("GET", file_name, false);
    file.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(file.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(file.status === 200 || file.status == 0)
            {
                allText = file.responseText;
                document.write(allText+"<BR>");
            }
        }
    }
    file.send(null);
}
function processTextValue()
{
 var in_arr = ['PROTO', 'TTL', 'TOS', 'ID', 'IpLen', 'DgmLen'];
 for(var i=0; i<in_arr.length; i++)
 {
  var c = in_arr[i];
  var n = allText.indexOf(c);
  var m = allText.indexOf(" ", n);
  n = n+c.length+1;
  document.write(c+": "+allText.substr(n, m-n)+"<BR>");
 }
}

readTextFile('your_file.txt');
processTextValue();
```

This is the result:

PROTO: 255
TTL: 0
TOS: 0x0
ID: 62399
IpLen: 20
DgmLen: 165